# Изменение гет параметров пагинации Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla

Вопрос в том как изменить стандартную джумловскую пагинацию вида `view=list&service=task&start=160 изменить на  ?page=1` и тд по нарастающей..
долго ковырялся в коде, и на форумах, но так и не нашел ничего похожего.
Очень прошу подсказать хотя бы где в джумле эти параметры определяются.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вам сюда https://www.google.com/search?q=joomla+1.5+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: при всем уважении, в ссылках представленых вашим гугл запросом есть  масса статей на изменение вида пагинации в теле страницы, а  не видом гетпарметров

Comment: Там есть статьи содержащие описание функций, которые формируют ссылки. Дальше уже эти функции надо разбирать.

Comment: этим вы хотите сказать что то что мне нужно находится  в /libraries/joomla/html/pagination.php ?

Comment: То есть вам нужен не пагинатор, а ЧПУ? Вот пример http://habrahabr.ru/post/113455/

Comment: Что бы быть точным мне нужно ЧПУ в пагинации

При переходи по страницам в URL передаются параметры по умолчанию это &start=160 (начинаем со 160 поста\вхождения\статьи\объекта  и тд) остальные гет параметры выдаются в качестве как я понимаю доп информации для определения какому компоненту обращаться, вместо всего этого я  хочу выводить www.site.ru/страница?page=3 и тд. сам ЧПУ на страницах уже настроен, логично предположить что часть добавляющаяся после перехода по ссылкам находится где то в модуле пагинации. и Вот вот вопрос где.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решена, как и описано в комментариях,посредcтвом JROUT